# Android - set seconds of date to zero

Tags: android, date

What is the right way to set the seconds of a Date to zero?

`myDate.setSeconds(0)` is deprecated.

I have found some post stating to substract two dates but I think this is much too complicated. There has to be a simple solution to just set the seconds (or other date/time components) to a certain value without using deprecated methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#setSeconds%28int%29), you have to use a [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) instead.

`Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();`
`cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);`

80% of the `Date` class is deprecated, switch to a `Calendar` instead.

Comment: Use `cal.setTime(myDate)` to initialize the `Calendar` to the desired time and `myDate = cal.getTime()` to get the modified `Date`.